# Meaning of "マスオさんする"

Tags: culture, anime

What is the meaning of "マスオさんする" in the following self-introduction extract?

> 家は表参道と近所ですが、特段お金持ちなわけではありません、妻の実家でマスオさんしてます。

My translation attempt:

> I live near Omotesando, but I am not rich: I "do M. Masuo" at my wife's parents' place.

Comment: Now my translation sounds very wrong at many levels...

Comment: The original sentence says 近所です so it'd be like 'I live "near" Omotesando st.', which means he lives in an upper-class residential area. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omotesand%C5%8D,_Tokyo
Although this person lives in this area, he says he's not especially rich, because/so he and his wife (and maybe their kids too) live in his wife's parents' house.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [Zokugo-dict](http://zokugo-dict.com/31ma/masuosan.htm):

> Masuo-san refers to the husband of Sazae-san in the popular anime "[Sazae-san](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sazae-san)", Fuguta Masuo. Masao-san lives together with Sazae-san and their parents at their parent's home, and it's come to mean a person who lives at their wife's parents' home.
>
> Furthermore, it's become used in a broader sense to refer to a son-in-law taken into a family (`婿{むこ}養{よう}子{し}`; in the Anime Masuo keeps his Fuguta name, so isn't a `婿養子`.)
>
> In particular, because in 1989 these kind of males increased, the expression "Masuo-san" became a trending phenomena.